# PHP find nearest of two dates

Tags: php, date

How would I get the nearest of two dates once I've defined them both as variables?

Here's the code to calculate the next Monday and Friday:

```
//calculates nearest Monday

$nextMonday = strtotime("next Monday");

$mondayParade = date("d/m/Y", $nextMonday);


//calculates nearest Friday

$nextFriday = strtotime("next Friday");

$fridayParade = date("d/m/Y", $nextFriday);
```

When echoing `$mondayParade` it displays `26/01/2015` which is correct.  `$fridayParade` also works as above but shows friday's date.

I'd like to be able to calculate which of these two dates is closest to my current date.

I read about also using `strtotime` for this but can't figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: Since both dates are in the future shouldn't just checking for the smaller one be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$now = time();
$nextMondayDiff = abs($now - $nextMonday);
$nextFridayDiff = abs($now - $nextFriday);

if ($nextMondayDiff < $nextFridayDiff) {
    echo 'Monday is closer';
} else {
    echo 'Friday is closer';
}
```

Or as @David points out in the comments, assuming both dates are always guaranteed to be in the future:

```
if ($nextMonday < $nextFriday) {
    echo 'Monday is closer';
} else {
    echo 'Friday is closer';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($nextMonday < $nextFriday) {
    echo "Monday";
} else {
    echo "Friday";
}
```